# How to search for title containing multiple words?

Tags: support, search

Go to Android Enthusiasts site. Then type in `title:calendar search` into the search field. Expect to only see answers in the returned results that contain titles that have *both* `calendar` and `search` in the title, but no that is not what you get. You get a lot more results that do not have both words in the title.

So, how does one get the search to do the above (without resorting to using Google, Bing, etc.).

Comment: That behavior wouldn't make sense for that search -- how would you distinguish searching for posts that have "search" in the body and "calendar" in the title from it?  Google's operators work the same way (i.e., `op:x y` only applies the operator to `x`).

Comment: You are right.  The syntax of searching for *both* `foo` and `bar` in Googles search engine would be `"foo" "bar"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little verbose, but it can be achieved like so:

> +title:calendar +title:search

However, that's not returning any results.

To see the constrained search in action, see [this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%20%2btitle:calendar%20%2btitle:facebook&submit=search) for this search:

> +title:calendar +title:facebook

Comment: Simply wonderful!